# iReport 3.7.3 crashing on startup on windows 10

Tags: ireport

I'm working on ADempiere project that has JasperReports Integration for which I need to download and run iReport 3.7.3 but it's crashing upon startup, do tell how to fix it;

I have already tried following:

1. changing installed location directory, one with no special characters or space in username as asked todo in this [wiki](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-crashes-when-starting-or-during-operation)
2. giving appropriate jdk i.e. 1.6 by setting environment variables JAVA HOME & PATH
3. Run in compatibility mode with windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, sharing it so that it might save someone else time

goto location where you installed ireport;
mine is D:\EOBI\ireport\iReport-3.7.3

here in \etc folder there will be file name ireport.conf edit it to give jdk path explicitly[image]